Supabase ambiguous embedding error persists after duplicate relation is deleted
I'm running supabase database using docker on my pc. I have an organizations table and a memberships table for my platform. My memberships has a foreign key reference to the organizations table via the organization's id.
CREATE TABLE organizations (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  creator_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  url VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  picture VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  mission TEXT NULL,
  purpose TEXT NULL,
  benefit TEXT NULL,
  appointment_procedures TEXT NULL,
  uniqueness TEXT NULL,
  meeting_schedule TEXT NULL,
  meeting_days VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  commitment_level org_commitment DEFAULT 'NONE',
  keywords TEXT NULL,
  tags TEXT NULL,
  is_returning BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
  returning_info TEXT NULL,
  state org_state DEFAULT 'PENDING',
  joinable BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
  join_instructions TEXT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE memberships (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  organization_id INT NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  role org_role DEFAULT 'MEMBER' NOT NULL,
  role_name VARCHAR(255),
  active BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (organization_id) REFERENCES organizations(id) on delete cascade,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) on delete cascade,
  CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_joins UNIQUE(organization_id, user_id)
);

However, I added an additional constraint to try to get an ON DELETE CASCADE to my relationship.
ALTER TABLE memberships
ADD CONSTRAINT delete_cascade FOREIGN KEY (organization_id) REFERENCES organizations(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;

Once I added this, I got an ambiguous embedding error when trying this query.
let { data, error } = await supabase
          .from("users")
          .select(
            `
              id,
              first_name,
              last_name,
              email,
              grad_year,
              picture,
              is_faculty,
              active,
              memberships (
                  id,
                  role,
                  role_name,
                  active,
                  organizations (
                      id,
                      name,
                      url,
                      picture,
                      meetings (
                          title,
                          description,
                          start_time,
                          end_time,
                          rooms (
                              name
                          )
                      )
                  )
              )
          `,
          )

I get this error
hint: "Try changing 'organizations' to one of the following: 'organizations!delete_cascade', 'organizations!memberships_organization_id_fkey'. Find the desired relationship in the 'details' key.", message: "Could not embed because more than one relationship was found for 'memberships' and 'organizations'"}
details: [
"delete_cascade using memberships(organization_id) and organizations(id)",
"memberships_organization_id_fkey using memberships(organization_id) and organizations(id)"
]

Which would make sense as there are two duplicate relationships. However, once I deleted the delete_cascade relationship, I still got the ambiguous embedding error stating that the delete_cascade relationship was still there. I tried deleting the whole database (by deleting all the volumes associated with it) and recreating it completely and the problem still persists. I checked every table and schema to see if any remaining data associated with the delete_cascade relationship still exists, but I haven't found anything.
EDIT:
when I try to specify the relationship by replacing
organization with organizations with organizations!delete_cascade, it says that delete_cascade relation doesn't exist. Yet, if I don't specify, it will say that delete_cascade and the foreign key are conflicting relations and I need to specify which one I want.
EDIT 2:
I added this erroneous constraint to other tables that want to reference organization as well. However, only the tables that I have queried produce this error. The other ones are perfectly fine (after deleting the constraint) (the error is only present in tables for which the frontend has caught).
EDIT 3:
I gave up, went to sleep, came back the next day and the bug was gone. Maybe it had something to do with my pc? I shut it down and reopened it.
